# Search a specified array index with a partial string

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any way that I can access the array index 1 and check if it contains the word "caret"?

```
$data = Array
(
[1] =>  <span style="display:block; background-color:#0098FF; margin-bottom:5px;"><a title="Training" style="color:white; font-size:12px;" onclick="myFunction2(127)" href="#">Algebra 123</a></span>
<span style="display:block; background-color:#0098FF; margin-bottom:5px;"> <a title="Training" style="color:white; font-size:12px;" onclick="myFunction2(158)" href="#">A1 Team</a></span>
<span style="display:block; background-color:#0098FF; margin-bottom:5px;"> <a title="Training" style="color:white; font-size:12px;" onclick="myFunction2(159)" href="#">A Team</a></span>
&nbsp;
<b class="caret"></b>

)
```

So far I've come across with this function

> preg_grep("/caret/", $data)

but what happens it also tried to access other index like 2,3 and so on. What alternative solution can I use?

Comment: specify the index of `$data` or try it with loop.

Comment: I'm using a foreach loop so it would access all of the data in the specified array. What I've given above is the snippet of the array

Comment: in `preg_grep("/caret/", $data)` use the index of array from loop.

Comment: Tried that but receives this error preg_grep() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given